# Laravel use MAX on join statement

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to find how can i use `MAX` on laravel QueryBuilder or Eloquent join statement, for example:

```
$userShoppings = \DB::table('shoppings')
    ->join('products', 'shoppings.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
    ->select('shoppings.*', 'products.name','products.amount','max(shoppings.ordering_count)')
    ->where('shoppings.user_ordering_ip', request()->ip())
    ->get();
```

in this code i want to get max `ordering_count` from `shoppings` table on `select` method, but i get this error:

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'max(shoppings.ordering_count)' in 'field list'
```

could any body help me to solve this problem?

**UPDATE for paste wrong result**

```
Collection {#449 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => {#446 ▼
      +"id": 11
      +"product_id": 25
      +"user_ordering_ip": "127.0.0.1"
      +"ordering_count": 3
      +"created_at": "2017-12-25 09:41:01"
      +"updated_at": "2017-12-25 09:41:01"
      +"amount": "128,440"
      +"max(shoppings.ordering_count)": 3
    }
    1 => {#445 ▼
      +"id": 10
      +"product_id": 26
      +"user_ordering_ip": "127.0.0.1"
      +"ordering_count": 1
      +"created_at": "2017-12-25 09:32:13"
      +"updated_at": "2017-12-25 09:32:13"
      +"amount": "137,614"
      +"max(shoppings.ordering_count)": 1
    }
    2 => {#452 ▼
      +"id": 9
      +"product_id": 49
      +"user_ordering_ip": "127.0.0.1"
      +"ordering_count": 2
      +"created_at": "2017-12-24 17:59:29"
      +"updated_at": "2017-12-24 18:35:25"
      +"amount": "110,092"
      +"max(shoppings.ordering_count)": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `DB::raw()`.  So:

```
$userShoppings = \DB::table('shoppings')
    ->join('products', 'shoppings.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
    ->select('shoppings.*', 'products.name','products.amount', DB::raw('max(shoppings.ordering_count)'))
    ->where('shoppings.user_ordering_ip', request()->ip())

    // note: you'll need to also group by all the columns
    // you're select in `shoppings.*`

    ->groupBy('products.name', 'products.amount', 'shoppings.id')
    ->get();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#raw-expressions

For the `groupBy()` issue you're experiencing, it's possible that you have `strict` mode enabled for MySQL.  You can disable it entirely in your `database.php` file by setting `strict => false` under your MySQL connection. However, this will disable all strict checks

If you want to simply disable `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`, you can add a `modes` key to your mysql connection in `database.php` as follows:

```
modes'     => [
                'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES',
                'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE',
                'NO_ZERO_DATE',
                'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO',
                'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER',
                'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
            ]
```

This will explicitly enable the other checks,  but omits `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`

Comment: i get this error:  `Syntax error or access violation: 1140 Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause (SQL: select `shoppings`.*, `products`.`name`, `products`.`amount`, max(shoppings.ordering_count) from `shoppings` inner join `products` on `shoppings`.`product_id` = `products`.`id` where `shoppings`.`user_ordering_ip` = '127.0.0.1')`

Comment: chances are the default behavior of your database has `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` set to `ON`.  In which case, if you're ussing aggregate functions like `MAX`, you need to group by the other columns in your select statement.  However because you select `shoppings.*`, you'll need to either select only the columns you need and and add those to the `group by` clause, or you'll need to list each of the columns from `shoppings` in your `group by` as well

Comment: problem of code resolved, but i get wrong result, for example with `MAX` i want to get max of `shoppings.ordering_count` in all result not columns, could you review my post? thanks